# my apple developers account is rejected

Tags: developer-program, app-store-connect

this is what pops up when i click the email link. "We are unable to activate your Apple Developer Program membership. We have received your purchase information and will email you shortly to verify additional details." what do i do? will it still charge my card?

Comment: It looks like the information you submitted was not sufficient so wait for the email.

Comment: apple sent me my receipt email. do i need to keep waiting

Comment: Nope, contact them to find out, but check your junk mail folder to see if it is there. If they deducted the money you are in :)

Comment: I would not recommend waiting for an email and would recommend making a direct support request - see my answer below as it's not clear which step has failed you.

Comment: they deducted the money and sent me a receipt also. but whenever i try to activate my now ios 7 iphone 4s it says i need to register.

Answer (score 1):

Like any problem with an item you purchase, contact the selling organization when the delivery of the sale isn't per the terms you expected. Call 1-800-MY-APPLE and give them your web order number.

---

In this case, the developer program is sold exclusively through the Apple online web store, so start with calling the toll free or local number for your Apple store and give them your order number.  But it gets far more complicated as I am about to write down...

The problem is likely email or payment details typo, and you will be charged and only the store support has the tools to refund your purchase or push it through as you prefer. Here is how things are supposed to work.

1. You pick an Apple ID for becoming a developer and start the buying process on this site: https://developer.apple.com/programs/
2. It gets you to log in and then makes your Apple ID a "potential developer" account and pushes your to the Apple Store to pay for the first year.
3. You do not have to use the same Apple ID to pay for that account - you just have to pay Apple Store (http://store.apple.com) the money.
4. Once they have your money, they kick off the process to make sure they know who owns the Apple ID used to register in step one. You may have to fax or email them legal documents, a copy of your driver's license or other government ID. This process is emailed to you and you have to sign in using the Apple ID from step one - not the one from step 2 (should they be different).
5. You then have to agree to certain legal terms relating to **NDA**, tax rules, electronic communication legal agreements, etc... and use the original Apple ID to signify that you agree to all Apple's terms.

If you didn't get the email to start step 4 - you have to deal with the Apple Store people at 1-800-MY-APPLE or [your local store contact](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/open/country_selector). If you got the email listing what you have to do to activate your Apple Developer account, you can deal with Apple Developer Support at 1-800-633-2152 (or [your local developer contact](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php))